# Kohana или Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, kohana, sql

Подскажите. Написали почти приложение на Codeigniter. Своя авторизация и регистрация, отправка уведомлений. И тут в голову брела мысль перенести на kohana. Выбор пал, потому что они похожи. Подскажите, стоит ли делать перенос, либо продолжать дорабатывать имеющееся?

Comment: Перенести просто из-за того, что они похожи? Нет, не стоит. Да и не настолько они похожи.  
Дорабатывайте.

Comment: нет не только что похожи. почитали комментарии по форумам и блогам. везде так рьяно говорят что CI уже умер, выкинуть его нужно, что лучше yii или kohana.

Comment: Тогда вот вам новость: kohana тоже больше не поддерживается. *Переходите на Laravel.*

Comment: решили оставить и дописывать :)

Comment: Kohana давно перестала развиваться, выберите другой фреймворк.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы на вашем месте задумался о переходе на Yii2, Symfony2 или Laravel. Так как они лидируют на рынке фреймворков. И как показывает практика, работу найти проще.

Comment: особенно симфони

Comment: Лидируют - это хороший аргумент. Вордпресс вон лидирует.

Comment: Ну, если бы вопрос был какую cms юзать. Вордпрес был бы в списках :(